# JSON.stringify not working on navigator.connection How to resolve?

Tags: javascript

On second console it showing some data but empty on first console log. How can I resolve this issue?

```js
var Network_data = navigator.connection;
console.log(JSON.stringify(Network_data));
console.log(Network_data);
```

Comment: What data you storing in Network_data?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is because of "function addEventListener() { [native code] }"

Comment: Just wondering why you are trying to do this?

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.stringify` is not working because the object itself doesn't have any properties they all belong to its parent. You should use a `for in` loop to get each key.

```js
var networkData = {};
for (var key in navigator.connection) {
  if (typeof navigator.connection[key] !== "function") {
    networkData[key] = navigator.connection[key];
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(networkData));
console.log(networkData);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need any of the prototype properties you could use

```
const { downlink, effectiveType, onchange, rtt, saveData } = navigator.connection; 
console.log(JSON.stringify({ downlink, effectiveType, onchange, rtt, saveData }));`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to nick correct answer that `JSON.stringify` doesn't serialize properties inherited, but only properties owned by the object, and won't stringify functions and circular references as well.

As a proof running [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on the instance will return an empty set because `navigator.connection` doesn't own any property

```js
console.log(Object.keys(navigator.connection));
```

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own property names